# How do I Use Pivot Tables to Create One Line Per Sub Category

Tags: excel, charts, analysis, pivot-table

Forgive me if this is not the "the best" place to ask excel questions.  I looked at the data analysis page and it looks like there aren't any real questions about excel in there.

I'm trying graph the sales of various products over a period of time.  I'm pulling it from the database in the format

```
Sales Person | End of Month | Sales | Product Type 
John Doe       1/31/2010      1,000   Widget A
John Doe       1/31/2010      2,000   Widget B
John Doe       1/31/2010      3,000   Widget C

John Doe       2/28/2010      5,000   Widget A
John Doe       2/28/2010      2,000   Widget B
John Doe       2/28/2010      3,000   Widget C
```

I then get  a summary like:

```
Year |  Month |  Product   | Total Sales
2010    Jan      Widget A    1,000
                 Widget B    2,000
                 Widget C    3,000 
        Feb      Widget A    5,000
                 Widget B    2,000
                 Widget C    3,000
```

The problem is that I'm wanting to graph The widgets as separate lines so that I can track sales against each other.  Over time.

However, excel treats it all as one "total" and then shows 3 points on the graph for each month rather than showing 3 separate lines.

No matter how I manipulate it, I can't get it to make 3 separate lines.

[image]

The example above should show how it works with two products.  I show how widget A and B are two points on the same line rather than belonging to two separate lines.

I have had success in the past for a different project when I hand entered information into a spreadsheet with the format of:

```
End of Month | Product A Sales | Product B Sales | Product C Sales
```

However, my current data is not in this format and it doesn't seem I can take the same approach...

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is an excellent example for a pivot chart. Choose Insert->Pivot Table->Pivot Chart (Excel 2007). Afterwards select your original table. Then use "End of Month" for the rows, "Product Type" for the columns, and "Sum of Sales" for data. Excel will then automatically create one line per widget type (if line is not selected as default graph type you may have to change the chart type).

Comment: I'm going to try this now. :)

Comment: Holy cow. I've totally forgotten that column tables even exist (If I ever knew...) ... This might save me in so many ways.

Comment: I CANNOT EXPLAIN how much you have helped me.  thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Always remember that pivot table/chart always allows multiple rows and columns

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, I think what you need might be a chart like this, the X-axis would be months while within each month, there would be several bars representing data of different widgets. Here I made an example based on your data.

[image]

As for data format, you should do some preprocessing to arrange your data into several (three in this case) subsets, each subset contains monthly sale data for a widget. It could look like the format below.

```
          Jan   Feb   
WidgetA   1000  5000  
WidgetB   2000  2000
WidgetC   3000  3000
```

As you could see, this is not an original Excel chart, I actually made this chart with the Funfun Excel add-in. This add-in allows you to use JavaScript directly in Excel so you could use powerful libraries like Chart.js or D3.js to make charts. Here in this example, I used Chart.js to create this chart.

Funfun also has an online editor which allows you to test your JavaScript code. For this example, you could check the details of the code on the link below.

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a25653acf76561801b732b4

If you are satisfied with the result, you could easily load the result into your Excel using the URL above. Here are some screenshots of what it looks like.

[image]

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun.***

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder the columns in the Pivot Table:

```
|  Product   | Month-Year | Total Sales
   Widget A    Jan 2010     1,000
               Feb 2010     5,000
   Widget B    Jan 2010     2,000
               Feb 2010     2,000
   Widget C    Jan 2010     3,000
               Feb 2010     3,000
```

That would make it easier to create three series, one for each widget. Make the chart an X-Y chart and the series will line up.

Comment: For XY it says " You cannot use an XY (Scatter), Bubble, or Stock chart type with a chart that has been created from Pivot Table data. Please select a different chart type. "

Comment: Howard's solution with a Pivot Chart is probably your best bet.